# How to inject into SignalR Hub from outside the web app container

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an application which controls a physical device in real time and I would like to allow control actions to be also executed in response to requests remote clients. I would like to use SignalR as the real time protocol for this and so have a self-hosting web component which provides a SignalR server.
I would like to inject an object created outside the web host into my hub class so that this can manage incoming messages and perform command actions elsewhere in the application.

[Dependency Injection in Asp .Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

The above link describes dependency injection, however this is only relevant for objects instantiated within the web host container. I would like to inject an object from outside the web host.

I can inject MyController object into MyHub from within the startup class as shown in the code below.

```
public class MyController : IMyController
{
    public Command(string message)
    {
        // .....
    }

}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        ProcessMessage(user, message);

    }
    public MyHub(IMyController myController)
    {
        _myController = myController;
    }

    void ProcessMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
        _myController.Command(message);
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
    }
    readonly IMyController _myController;
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyController, MyController>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
        });
    }
}
```

The signalR webhost is created from within my app as follows.

```
public static void Start()
{
    CreateHostBuilder().Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:2803");
        });
```

I would be grateful if someone could advise how to inject a MyController object instantiated outside the Startup class into the MyHub instance.

I understand that HubContext can be used to send message to clients from outside the web app component but I would essentially like to receive messages from clients and perform actions outside of the web host.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean "outside of the web app"?

Comment: Perhaps this is the wrong phrase. Webhost would be more appropriate. My app is running a web host and performing actions from outside the web host. The web host is   used to create a signal R server to receive command actions from clients. Please let me know if this is still not clear.

Comment: If you want to use MyHub inside MyController, just create a new instance of the HubConnectionBuilder and connect to SignalR inside your controller. There's a .Net client available for server side code

Comment: It's not clear whether you have 2 apps, a web app and some other app, or you are referring to different parts of your web app as webhost and something else. Perhaps you can show the code of the "outside" thing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. I've updated my description. There is one app, which performs lots device control functionality and has its own IOC. Inside this app is a signalR server created within a self-hosting web component. I'm new to this so don't know the correct terminology. Please let me know if this is not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
public class HubService : Hub
{

    private readonly IDeviceService _deviceService;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public HubService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _deviceService = _serviceProvider.GetService<IDeviceService>();
    }
}
```

and Startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDeviceService,DeviceService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new HubService(builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()));
```

I use IServiceProvider to create another services.

**The same solution:**
I create EngineContext.cs

```
public class EngineContext
{
    private static IServiceProvider _ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public static void SetServiceProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Resolve dependency
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of resolved service</typeparam>
    /// <returns>Resolved service</returns>
    public static T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {
        return (T)Resolve(typeof(T));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resolve dependency
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">Type of resolved service</param>
    /// <returns>Resolved service</returns>
    public static object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        return _ServiceProvider?.GetService(type);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resolve dependencies
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of resolved services</typeparam>
    /// <returns>Collection of resolved services</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>()
    {
        return (IEnumerable<T>)_ServiceProvider.GetServices(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
EngineContext.SetServiceProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider());
```

And using:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IWorkContext _WorkContext = EngineContext.Resolve<IWorkContext>();
    protected ILanguageService _LanguageService = EngineContext.Resolve<ILanguageService>();
    protected IRoleService _RoleService = EngineContext.Resolve<IRoleService>();
    protected ICountryService _CountryService = EngineContext.Resolve<ICountryService>();
}
```